# Создать функцию по значению переменной

Tags: python

Допустим, у меня есть переменная `func_name = 'qwerty'`.
Мне нужно сделать:

```
def qwerty():
```

Используя переменную `func_name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вообще, это выглядит как ошибка проектирования, но можно использовать такой "ужасный" код, сохранив в переменную заранее заготовленный шаблон функции

```
def template(a):
    print(a)

func_name = 'qwerty'

globals()[func_name] = template

qwerty(25)
```

Comment: Ух ты, красиво, я до такого не смог додуматься, был уверен, что кроме exec вариантов никаких)

Answer (score 3):

Динамическое создание функций - достаточно известная задача, самое правильное решение - фабричный метод/класс.

Динамическое создание функции с именем из переменной можно выполнить, например, при помощи  конструкции `exec`:

```
func_name = 'qwerty'

exec(f"def {func_name}(): pass")

print(qwerty()) # None
```

Comment: Хм... Интересная функция, где можно подробней ознакомиться с ней?

Comment: @ΝNL993 почитать подробнее можете в официальной документации: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec

Comment: @ΝNL993 но вообще, использование функций `eval`/`exec` - считается очень плохой практикой и надо стараться избегать их, особенно в реальном приложении, потому что не всегда есть полная возможность контролировать, что именно будет протранслировано в код

Answer (score 1):

Ну и через lambda тоже можно, а там уже смотря что функция делать должна:

```
globals()[func_name] = lambda x: x * 2
```

Comment: ну это тоже самое - все равно код заранее написать надо

Comment: @splash58 Да задача всё-равно толком непонятна